# How to check if the URL contains a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am using window.location.href.indexOf to check if URL contains a string and works very well for something like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) {
      alert("your url contains the name franky");
```

But it doesn't work to check if URL contains any number.
The following always calls the alert, even if no number is in the URL.

```
if (
window.location.href.indexOf("0") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("1") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("2") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("3") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("4") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("5") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("6") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("7") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("8") === -1 || 
window.location.href.indexOf("9") === -1
)
{ alert("false"); }
```

Comment: try to use window.location.pathname

Comment: use a regex: window.location.pathname.match(/\d/) != null --->contains a number

Comment: What does the URL look like? Where is the number within it? Part of a route, or in a querystring value?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: "The following always calls the alert, even if no number is in the URL." - That's because you are effectively testing against the existence of all numbers 0-9 in that example. That code translates to, "if the URL doesn't contain all numbers 0-9, then `alert("false")`

Comment: Little surprised no-one has mentioned this - change all your `||` to `&&` and you'll get what you want:  https://jsfiddle.net/zkshm9dn/ or use your original condition:  `> -1` with `||`

Comment: You've changed the negativity of your test (from true to false) so you also need to swap the `||` to `&&`.  If you kept it positive, then keep the `||`.  You're saying *if it does not have 1 **or** it does not have 2* well it should be clear than if it's just "2" then it clearly doesn't have "1" so fails the first test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As gaetanoM suggested, a regular expression would be the easiest way to do it.

```js
if (window.location.href.match(/\d/)) {
  alert('contains a number');
} else {
  alert('does not contain a number');
}
```